# Sublimetext USER settings issue

Tags: settings, sublimetext3, application-settings

I must say I didn't expect this issue to be happening with sublimetext, let me expand a bit more.

Dunno which setting on the code below is making me see this weird effect on the TAB of the app check the screen plz:

[image: sublime text TAB effect]

```js
{
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "caret_extra_width": 1,
    "caret_style": "phase",
    "close_windows_when_empty": false,
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Predawn/predawn.tmTheme",
    "copy_with_empty_selection": false,
    "drag_text": false,
    "draw_minimap_border": true,
    "enable_tab_scrolling": false,
    "font_face": "Source Code Pro",
    "font_options":
    [
        "no_round"
    ],
    "font_size": 14,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
    ],
    "line_padding_bottom": 1,
    "line_padding_top": 1,
    "match_brackets_content": false,
    "match_selection": false,
    "match_tags": false,
    "open_files_in_new_window": false,
    "overlay_scroll_bars": "enabled",
    "preview_on_click": false,
    "rulers":
    [
        80
    ],
    "scroll_past_end": true,
    "scroll_speed": 5.0,
    "show_full_path": false,
    "sidebar_default": true,
    "tab_completion": false,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "theme": "Soda Light.sublime-theme",
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
    "vintage_start_in_command_mode": true,
    "word_wrap": true
}
```

Comment: Did you update your theme without restarting Sublime?

Comment: If restarting means: close sublimetext and open it again, the answer is YES, serveral times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`Theme - Soda` docs](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Soda), there are two different `.sublime-theme` files for each theme - `Soda XXX.sublime-theme` for Sublime Text 2, and `Soda XXX 3.sublime-theme` for ST3, where `XXX` is either `Dark` or `Light`. Since you're using ST3, your `"theme"` setting should be"

```
"theme": "Soda Light 3.sublime-theme",
```

This should correct the issues you are having with tab titles. Make sure you *completely* restart Sublime after making the change - don't just close the window and reopen it, you need to select **`Sublime Text -> Quit Sublime Text`**, then reopen it.